# Errors in attempting to obtain a response for a SELECT SQL command in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a project that utilizes a checkout function. For this I have used a datagridview element in vb and my goal was to take values from said  datagridview and put them inside a Microsoft Access database, however, when attempting to use a SELECT SQL command I receive an "Index out of range" error.

My code is here:

```
Dim findcurrentstock as string = "SELECT '" & checkoutview(0,i).value & "'FROM Tides WHERE Times = '" & actualstarttime & "'

cmd = new oledbcommand(findcurrentstock, connection)
Response = cmd.Executereader

If response.read = false then
    msgbox("ERROR MESSAGE")
else
    currentstock = response(checkoutview(0,i).value).tostring
    msgbox("currentstock")
```

Comment: Why is the field name dynamic? A SELECT does not 'put' data into database, it pulls data.

Comment: I was first trying to attempt to pull data when determining the current values for the stock of an item and then subtract the amount taken from the stock. Which is why i have attempted to select first

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. Stock balance should be calculated from raw transaction data when needed.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL statement would not use apostrophe delimiters for field name. Use [ ] instead. Also, a space in front of FROM. If Times is a date/time datatype, use # delimiters. Missing closing quote mark.

`Dim findcurrentstock as string = "SELECT [" & checkoutview(0,i).value & "] FROM Tides WHERE Times = #" & actualstarttime.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"`

Comment: And to time must be converted to a properly formatted string expression.

Comment: The actual SQL command doesn't seem to be the issue. The issue occurs when the program goes to get the value from the Access DB. The error it returns says that the indexisoutofrange but it doesnt make sense, i have a database filled with plenty of data values and i just cant seem to retrieve this specific one. I have used similar code for other SELECT commands before and it just doesnt seem to like this specific table.Perhaps this is an issue with access? The data im trying to obtain is in the long text type so would this affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing where you are getting the value of `i`, but keep in mind that the columns and rows are numbered from `0` not `1`. So, a "typical" cause of an "Index out of range" error is using `i` when you may need `i - 1` instead.

Comment: I have used msgboxes to display the query to me when the program runs and it seems to be taking my values for checkoutview(0,i) fine. For reference the value is 'Red Kayak' and it displays perfectly fine. However when i reach the response part of the program, it doesnt seem to like to gather a response using this same value 'Red Kayak'